# Proof of a formula for generalized Fibonacci numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

I have done the verification for
$$U_rU_{n−1} − U_{r−1}U_n = (−1)^{r−1}U_{n−r}$$
I realized when I was doing for $n=k+1$,
the expression $U_rU_k − U_{r−1}U_{k+1}$ would not equate to $(−1)^{r−1}U_{n−r}$. 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: An identity may be useful: $$U_rU_{n-1}-U_{r-1}U_n=U_rU_{n-1}-U_{r-1}(U_{n-1}+U_{n-2})=U_{n-1}[U_r-U_{r-1}]-U_{r-1}U_{n-2}$$

$$\implies U_rU_{n-1}-U_{r-1}U_n=-(U_{r-1}U_{n-2}-U_{r-2}U_{n-1})$$